# How do i convert an Object of mongodb to an String or integer in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

actually I am fetching data from MongoDB into 'document' object. So, I want to use that data further. I have to convert that object into an integer format or a String.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("OLTP");
MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> collection = database.getCollection("Item");

Document document = collection                      //this document object.
.find(new BasicDBObject("i_name","Mobile"))
.projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("i_price"), Projections.excludeId())).first();
```

In this code, I fetched price of a Mobile. Because I want to multiply that price to the quantity, that is not possible without converting the object into integer form.

### NOTE: I have tried.

```
price=document.toString();
```

or

```
price=Integer.parseInt(document);
```

or

```
price=Integer.parceInt(toStrint(document));
```

Please give the relevant answer, with related to MongoDB and Java.
Thank you.

Comment: You can try document.getInteger("i_price") to get the integer value. Actually you should change it to Double using document.getDouble("i_price")

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB Document class is a representation of a document as a Map, so you need to get the value with the key.

```
document.getInteger("your_value_key");
```

http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/Document.html#getInteger-java.lang.Object-

Comment: Hi Alvaro, I have tried this but still it is generating an error message.

Comment: Actually, now it is not generating an error message. But still, it is not printing anything on  a print that value of price.                                                                                         int value = document.getInteger("i_price");
                     System.out.println("Mobile price "+value);

Comment: It is really hard to tell why it is not printing anything without code, db model....but that is the way to get an int value from Document object